# service onStartCommand method

Tags: android, android-service

I was wondering if two different threads calls `startService` on service `A` at the same time, does the service execute `onStartCommand()` for **both of them separately or does one cancel the other**?

I want to understand services in `Android`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Service` will only be created once but `onStartCommand()` will be called as many times as someone calls `startService()` and have the `Intent` used to start the service passed into it. This way you can have the service respond to different actions within each `Intent`.

Note that *a single call* to `stopService()` is all that's required to kill the service, no matter how many times someone calls `startService()`. See the description of the [`Service` lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more information.